# Porting from struts2-dojo to jquery: periodically update a frame inside a jsp

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, dojo

In my jsp I have this:

```
<s:url action="listarichiesteAjax.action" var="richiesteAjax" >
    <s:param name="messaggioUtente" value="messaggioUtente"></s:param>
</s:url>
<sx:div href="%{#richiesteAjax}" updateFreq="10000" preload="true">
```

This piece of code refresh every 10sec (calling the action listarichiesteAjax that execute a query) a JSP called from the action. I would like to port this and use jQuery.
Do I have to change my actions structure? Or do I just need to edit this jsp?

How do I will modify the code?
(I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985023/struts-2-dojo-vs-dojo-js/16987761#16987761) that it's preferable use jQuery instead of Struts2-jQuery plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the DivTag documentation](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DivTag):

```
updateFreq    false    false    Number    
              How often to reload the content (in milliseconds). e.g. 5000
```

So it is there and it also has the same name.

You only need to change `<sx:` to `<sj:` , import jquery tags:

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
```

and put `<sj:head/>` in your `<head>` section, where you should already have `<sx:head/>`

Comment: But is it not preferable to use plain jQuery like you wrote in the other post?

Comment: I've applied the edit you suggested (the previous syntax was the one to use [when the libraries are in the EAR and the WAR is skinny](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19380836/1654265)). About the raw jQuery vs jQuery plugin, I've not suggested one over the other in my linked answer; the plugin is highly maintained, and since it saves you a huge coding work, it may be the best choice. If you instead are changing framework frequently, jumping eg. from Struts2 to Spring MVC to JSF 2, and want to learn to do it once, using raw jQuery would be smarter.